# accessing $_POST data of dynamically created input values

Tags: php

I have a form with a couple of text areas and then about 20 input fields.

The input fields are created dynamically, using a loop and are created from values in my db (countries)

My code is:

```
$options = '';
$country_code = '';
$query = $DB->query("SELECT country_code, country_id, IF(country_code = ".$country_code."', '', '') AS sel FROM exp_sme_countries WHERE site_id='".$this->settings['site_id']."' ORDER BY country_name ASC");
           foreach ($query->result as $row)
           {
            $options .= '<label>' . 'Phrase for ' .  $this->settings['countries'][$row['country_code']] . '</label>' . '<br />';
                            $options .= '<input style="width: 100%; height: 5%;" id="country_data" type="text"  name="' . $row['country_id'] . '"  />' . '<br /><br />';
                            $options .= '<input type="hidden" name="country_id" id="country_id" value="' . $row['country_id'] . '"   />';

           }
```

This outputs examples such as:

```
input style="width: 100%; height: 5%;" id="country_data" type="text"  name="68"  />
input style="width: 100%; height: 5%;" id="country_data" type="text"  name="28"  />
```

Now my problem is, how do I get the values of these input fields?

I have looked at outputting $_POST, but this seems to return data that I can't really access.

Can these values be accessed in any way?

Or do I need to change the way I'm doing things?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're outputting duplicate html ids - don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like said above, you do have

```
name="country_id"
```

probably like 70+ times as well.  That's going to be a problem.

You can do:

```
name="country_id[]"
```

and get an array in PHP after it gets POSTed.

Also, are you sure you are POSTing?  Seems not if $_POST is empty..

Answer (score 1):

change your 'name' of the fields as follows:

```
name="p_' . $row['country_id'] . '"
```

then you can go:

```
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (substr($key, 0, 2) == "p_") {
            $country_id[str_replace("p_", "", $key)] = $value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This seems to work. I just need to plug it into a loop to get everything into my db tables. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST[68]` and `$_POST[28]` will return the values you need. You should use alpha keys `(country_code)` instead. If for some reason those numeric IDs in your database change, you'll run into trouble maintaining your code. HTML also requires you to use unique element IDs for a document to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Your best solution would be to create an array with the HTML so it posts in the format you want... refer to this post for an example: [PHP: help with array structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226220/php-help-with-array-structure/4226268#4226268)